# Extract trees and weights from trained xgboost model

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, xgboost, lightgbm

I have already trained an xgboost model with about X trees. I want to create some replicas of the model with exact same hyper parameters, but prune the number of trees. for example i want to create a model with same weight and parameters with just half the number of trees . Is it possible to do this using xgboost api .

I tried a naive quick approach of de-serializing a trained xgboost model and resetting the booster_params['num_boost_round'] to half of what it was. But this didnt seem to impact any of the model quality and prediction scores, implying this parameter is not used when scoring/evaluation.

The only options left is to dump a text or pmml file , parse it back with a subset of trees. Wondering if it is possible to do it with xgboost api itself (like changing a parameter that would bring the same effect) without converting to a separate representation/format and parsing myself.

Comment: might be a duplicate to my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626792/xgboost-force-a-trained-booster-object-to-be-defined-by-x-trees-boosts

Comment: Also, you might find an answer in my question when trying to predict you can use any number of sub-trees you've already trained.

Comment: @EranMoshe : thanks for the link. Seems like that would work. But if i serialize the model (convert to pmml , convert to text ) , it would still dump the original number of trees , is there  a way i can make it serialize with only a given number of trees but with alll other params the same

Comment: That's exactly my question. And it has not been answered. You can try retrain the model with the best number of trees you've found...